# if else statement within a function is breaking function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am 90% finished with a simple calculator that tells you the cost difference between shopping in person vs shopping online. You can view it below. My only problem is the last sentence. It says

> You should shop in person. You’ll save €x everytime you shop.

X updates fine, just try it out and see. My problem is I want to display a string. The value of the string will be determined by an if/else statement.

If (cost of shopping in person < cost of shopping online)  {display the above statement with x = difference in cost} Else {You should shop online. You'll save €x everytime you shop.}

I have included below my code, with my attempted if/else statement commented out because it breaks the code. I have tried just about everything and I'm at a roadblock. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I see my problem. This is probably a rookie error. Thanks guys. To fix my code I simply removed the comments I previously added and replaced my var summaryFull with the below line:

```
      var summaryFull = (summary>0) ? "You should shop online. You will save" + summary + "everytime you shop." : "You should shop in person. You will save" + (summary * -1) + "everytime you shop.";
```

```js
    var incomePerHour = document.getElementById("income_p_hour");
    var timeToShop = document.getElementById("time_to_shop");
    var deliveryCharge = document.getElementById("delivery_charge");
    var timeToDeliver = document.getElementById("time_to_deliver");

    var inPersonElement = document.getElementById("inPersonCost");
    var deliveryElement = document.getElementById("deliveryCost");
    var summaryElement = document.getElementById("summary");
  //  var summaryFullElement = document.getElementById("summaryFull")

    var inPersonTextElement = document.getElementById("inPersonCostText");
    var deliveryTextElement = document.getElementById("deliveryCostText");
    var summaryTextElement = document.getElementById("summaryText");
    //var summaryFullTextElement = document.getElementById("summaryFullText");



    function updateProfit() {
      var inPersonCost = ((Number(incomePerHour.value)/60) * Number(timeToShop.value)).toFixed(2);
      var deliveryCost = (((Number(incomePerHour.value)/60) * Number(timeToDeliver.value)) + Number(deliveryCharge.value)).toFixed(2);
      var summary = (inPersonCost - deliveryCost).toFixed(2);
    /*  var summaryFull = (if ((parseInt(summary)) > 0){
        "You should shop online. You will save" + summary + "everytime you shop.";
      } else {
        "You should shop in person. You will save" + (summary * -1) + "everytime you shop.";
      })*/
      inPersonElement.value = inPersonCost;
      deliveryElement.value = deliveryCost;
      summaryElement.value = summary;
      //summaryFullElement.value = summaryFull;

      inPersonTextElement.innerText = inPersonCost;
      deliveryTextElement.innerText = deliveryCost;
      summaryTextElement.innerText = summary;
    //  summaryFullTextElement.innerText = summaryFull;

    }

    incomePerHour.onchange = timeToShop.onchange = deliveryCharge.onchange = timeToDeliver.onchange = updateProfit;
```

```html
    <form method="POST">
      How much do you value your time per hour? <input type="int" id="income_p_hour"> <br />
      How much of your time does it take to go grocery shopping in person in minutes? <input type="int" id="time_to_shop"> <br />
      How much is the delivery charge? <input type="int" id="delivery_charge"> <br />
      How much of your time does it take to order your groceries online in minutes? <input type="int" id="time_to_deliver"> <br />

  <!--  <input type="hidden" id="profit" name="profit"/>
   Profit: $<span id="profitText"></span> -->
<br>
    <input type="hidden" id="inPersonCost" name="inPersonCost"/>
    Cost of shopping in person: <span id="inPersonCostText"></span> <br />
    <input type="hidden" id="deliveryCost" name="deliveryCost"/>
    Cost of shopping online: <span id="deliveryCostText"></span>
<br>
You should shop in person. You'll save €<input type="hidden" id="summary" name="summary"/><span id="summaryText"></span> everytime you shop.
<br>
<!-- <input type="hidden" id="summaryFull" name="summaryFull"/><span id="summaryFullText"></span> -->
    </form>
```

Comment: Yes, you can't assign a statement to a variable, use [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead.

Comment: you probalby want to use a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if` block doesn't *return* anything.  It's a statement, not an expression.  So this structure is incorrect:

```
var x = if (something) { 1 } else { 2 }
```

You can use a ternary conditional operator, which is an expression, to evaluate to a value:

```
var x = something ? 1 : 2;
```

Or set the value within the `if` block:

```
var x = 0;
if (something) {
  x = 1;
} else {
  x = 2;
}
```

But you can't mix the two approaches like that.